# Steam - Left 4 Dead 2 showing twice

Tags: games, steam

I recently installed Steam and I see the game `Left 4 Dead 2` appear twice, once with a *Beta* tag and another with the same tag but between parenthesis. Here's a screen capture of what I'm seeing:

[image: steam]

What's the difference between these two?

A few days ago I installed the one with the *Beta* tag in parenthesis and today I purchased the `Left 4 Dead + Left 4 Dead 2` bundle (http://store.steampowered.com/sub/2487/) but so far `Left 4 Dead 2` hasn't showed up in my Library. Is it the same as the one I already installed? Should I wait a bit more for it to start downloading (it's been ~30 minutes)? This is really confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left 4 Dead 2 for Linux has not left Beta yet. It is still being tested, as the port to Linux is relatively young.

*Left 4 Dead 2 (Beta)* is the actual game, while *Left 4 Dead 2 Beta* is the actual beta (as in: the version that is in active development, as opposed to the port).

Therefore, *Left 4 Dead 2 (Beta)* is most likely the one you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks FEichinger. I still don't understand what is going to happen now that I bought the _Left 4 Dead 2_ game through Steam. Why was I able to install and play _Left 4 Dead 2 (Beta)_ before I had purchased it? Should it be updated now that I bought it? Should I expect anything to change?

Comment: First part is not true, it is ["officially released on Linux"](http://store.steampowered.com/news/?appids=550), but you are right that it is the one they are looking for.

Comment: @Gabriel I believe *that* is because there is currently a Free Weekend for Left 4 Dead 2. ;)

Comment: @Chris Huh, interesting. Still doesn't show up in my library.

Comment: @FEichinger it shows Beta in mine too.  Not sure why and I haven't tried to play my friends that didn't have the Beta version, but that's what I read from the news post.

Comment: @Chris Well, I'm gonna leave it the way it is right now until that beta tag disappears. Steam obviously still calls it a Beta, even if Valve officially doesn't. :/